# Update font style for Android MenuItem

Tags: android, fonts, menu, styles, menuitem

I got a problem with the android code. I have a Menu with a SubMenu and I want to set the font style to bold for (Sub)MenuItem if it was clicked by the user. So the menu acts like a filter list, where you can select only one filter at the time and the selected MenuItem become bold. I have to do this programatically, benause the categories were generated/added dynamically.

The menu structure looks like this

```
...
<menu>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_sort_alphabetically" android:title="by name"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_sort_value" android:title="by value"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_sort_category" android:title="by category">
        <menu android:id="@+id/menu_category"
            android:checkableBehavior="single">
            <item android:title="Category 1"></item>
            <item android:title="Category 2"></item>
            ...
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
...
```

I tried several ways, but haven't found any solution or idea. It would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: did you tried overriding onPrepareOptionsMenu??

Comment: I tried, but I got no real solution. Cause this method is (AFAIK) only called when the menu is created and I need to "update" the menu if the user clicks on one item in it

Comment: call inValidateOptionsMenu() to update